# JSON Tweet Post Date

Tags: ios, json, twitter

I have a twitter feed in my iOS app. I have the following info: username and user's post but I was wondering if and how I can get the timestamp of the post what do I look for in the JSON. I just want the date it was posted on. Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Date: %@",[tweet objectForKey:@"created_at"]];